# linux mv command weirdness

Tags: linux, file-management, file-transfer

can anyone tell me why when I type:

```
mv -f ./tmp/members ./
```

I get:

```
mv: cannot move `./tmp/members' to a subdirectory of itself, `./members'
```

And moreover the correct way to move this directory?

Also, there is already a directory at ./members ... I want to completely overwrite this directory, not just add the new contents to it.

I've discovered that this works:

```
mv tmp/members members
```

but only for new contents... the old contents are still left behind...

Thanks!

-Eric

Comment: Please try asking on superuser.com - SO is intended for programming questions.

Comment: [Crossposted](http://serverfault.com/questions/162037/linux-mv-command-weirdness) on ServerFault (please don't crosspost).

Comment: We need to know what directory you are in when you run the command because ./ means the current directory.

Comment: I just gave it a try in OS X and couldn't replicate your issue.  Does it possibly depend on the flavour of Linux you're using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in /tmp when you run the first one, that would account for the error message. The easiest way to do what you want is to rm -rf the target and then mv the original dir to that location.